# Lubuntu 18.10 pcmanfm-qt does not access samba shares

Tags: lubuntu, nautilus, samba, lxqt

When I try to access shares with pcmanfm-qt in Lubuntu 18.10, it only shows the `/` directory on the Lubuntu machine. I downloaded Nautilus, and it does not have this problem. Is there a fix in pcmanfm-qt? Alternatively, how can Nautilus be made default file manager in Lubuntu, and/or be given a menu entry or taskbar icon for one click start? Thank you for your help.

I set up a shared drive on my desktop running Ubuntu 18.10 which I would like to access from my laptop, on which I have installed Lubuntu 18.10. When I open PCMan and click on Network, the shared drive is visible. If I click on the shared drive, PCMan opens the Home directory on the laptop instead. If I perform the same operation with Nautilus, the shared drive is opened. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: In what way does not not access Samba shares?  Can you please provide more information.  I use NFS, but loaded an old NAS device that uses samba, and with `pcmanfm-qt` I could access my shares as I'd expect. For me I accessed it via path (for me it's quickest) which may not be how you do, or want to - but please explain.  Lubuntu 18.10 is Qt based; Nautilus is GTK+ thus is wasteful of memory/resources and a very poor choice as a default. but please clarify.  *Sorry not sure what you meant by 'fiex in PACMan''*

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer about the problem. The spelling should have been "fix".

Comment: Here is the detail you request. I set up a shared drive on my desktop running Ubuntu 18.10 which I would like to access from my laptop, on which I have installed Lubuntu 18.10. When I open PCMan and click on Network, the shared drive is visible. If I click on the shared drive, PCMan opens the Home directory on the laptop instead. If I perform the same operation with Nautilus, the shared drive is opened. Thanks for your attention. I'm now trying to switch to SSH.

Comment: Please add the additional info to your question, as only a small number of users read comments (the more people who see it, the more chance of a fast & useful answer to you).   How you access the share is not how I would, and I will endeavour to later boot an old 18.10 qa-test install & access a samba nas device (which won't have been setup thus may better reflect what you see).

Comment: I booted the Lubuntu 18.10 box, brought it up-to-date, and tried using `pcmanfm-qt` to view my old nas device (which has samba enabled) and it saw this box [19.04] & others, but not my nas. Yes clicking some had me view my (local) / drive which fits what you describe (only not Home). I tried adding `dolphin` (it uses Qt like Lubuntu and thus is far lighter than gnome's `nautilus`) but didn't get any further.  Back in `pcmanfm-qt` I entered `smb://buffalo122/buffalo`  (my device name; I didn't want to keep typeing IP address so buffalo122 was added to my hosts file)

Comment: .. which was the closest I got, it got a "Error: Failed to mount Windows share..."  Looking in `dmesg` I can see the reason, but currently I'm not sure how to add params I use when mounting my shares via commands, so I'd suggest mounting via `/etc/fstab` (file system table) or via command (saved to a file, I've added a `/usr/local/bin/mount_122` command that mounts the share correctly & run it before backups - but this being only a qa-test box had no need for that).  I've not used gui to mount before, and was not successful here sorry.

Comment: Once mounted via command, or in `/etc/fstab`  (where `noauto` may be handy if you don't want to use it all the time, refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) I can use `pcmanfm-qt` & file.manager's on the gui normally & treat the share as a normal folder. It also showed the same icon I saw in my 'Network' folder for my mounted directory.  *I also like the control I have via doing it this way, I can use names that mean something to me*

Comment: thank you for your comments guiverc. I would like to get pcmanfm working properly but I am a bit confused about how to do so. Would you mind listing the steps in order so that I may follow your procedure.

Comment: Meanwhile, I am using Nemo, which is able to display contents of shares.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for (*listing steps* to what?). In the end I reverted to mounting via command (`mount` command at terminal), or automating it via placing an entry in /etc/fstab (file system table). This is standard and works for any Ubuntu.  A quick scan looking for wiki.ubuntu.com reveals https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide  which mentions Nautilus, so I wonder if you've already seen it, but https://askubuntu.com/questions/313093/how-do-i-mount-a-cifs-share-via-fstab-and-give-full-rw-to-guest maybe more helpful.

Comment: I'd suggest working out the command that mounts your 'share', as from that, the entry that is needed in your /etc/fstab is the same just slightly massaged.  Nemo is a fork of Nautilus, so equally 'heavy' but without the 'warranty' provided to Nautilus.  Over the years I've had to add a few extra options to my commands/entries (last one was in response to WannaCry to protect windows clients), but I'm unsure what you're after as what I use would ending up looking by the prior askubuntu link (match my NAS device params, not yours)